# How to take spin dump of Microsoft Edge process on mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-edge

Can you please share the steps that need to be followed to take a spin dump of Edge browser on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

The spindump is a feature available on macOS we can extract the state of the application in the form of an apple crash dump file.Here are the steps that you should follow to create the apple dump file:

- Launch Microsoft Edge application
- Launch Activity Monitor, which can be found in the Utilities folder located inside the main Applications folder.

[image: ActivityMonitor]

- In Activity Monitor, make sure that CPU is selected and select "Microsoft Edge" from the list under Process Name:

[image: ActivityMonitor2]

- Switch back to "Microsoft Edge" and repeat your steps until the freeze occurs. While the freeze is occurring in "Microsoft Edge", go to back to Activity Monitor, click on the gear and select spindump.
- After the process is complete a new window opens up to display the diagnostic. Click the "Save..." button in the upper right and save the file to your desktop.